# differentiability of unit sphere

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that 
$$x^2 + y^2 +z^2 = 1$$ is differentiable. I have first made the equation a function of $x,y$ that is $$f(x,y) = \sqrt{(1 - x^2 - y^2)}$$ However, now I am confused, can I show that the partial differentials are differentiable and hence the total derivative is differentiable or need I plug directly into the definition: if so, how do I go about doing this? I get stuck trying to show that the function indeed goes to zero using the general definition of differentiability.

Comment: Careful; _functions_ and not geometric objects are (may be)differentiable. Try expressing the function as a composition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that it is functions that may or not be differentiable. Remember too, that if $f,g$ are both (somewhere) differentiable, then the composition $f\circ g$ is differentiable when $g(x)$ is in the set where $f$ is differentiable. Can you write your function f as a composition of (somewhere)-differentiable functions?

Comment: I'm guessing then g(x) = sqrt(x) and f(x,y) = (1 - x^2 - y^2), so then you could just state that g(x) is differentiable and show by the general definition the f(x,y) is differentiable so the composition is also differentiable.

Comment: You're right, but remember that square root is not defined everywhere; you also need to show that f(g(x)) is defined.

Comment: May i also ask, how do i now show that the derivative of f(x,y) is continuous, can i just show that that the directional derivatives are continuous and hence the the total derivative is also continuous, or, is the theorem only an "if" clause, in that, if the total derivative is continuous then the directional derivatives are also continuous.

Comment: Sure:If the partials exist and are both continuous, then f(x,y) is differentiable, and differentiability implies continuity.